# Get all subfolders and files in a folder google drive api android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to list all subfolders and folders in a google drive account using google drive api. When the folder only containing subfolders then I only get the first subfolders when using DriveFolder.getChildren. If the folder only contains files I will not get any children with the same call, i.e DriverFolder.getChildren.
I have also tried with query the folder for a specific file, that of course exists, but I do not get any hits on that either.

Code sample:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //mGoogleApiClient is connected and mRootDrive is a folder in the drive account
        DriveFolder f = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGoogleApiClient, mRootDriveId);
        MetadataResult fDataresult = f.getMetadata(mGoogleApiClient).await();
        // Will print the right name of the folder
        Log.i(Tag, "Folder name " + fDataresult.getMetadata().getTitle());

        MetadataBufferResult result = f.listChildren(mGoogleApiClient).await();
        // Will be one even if there are 10 folders
        Log.i(Tag, "Number of children " + result.getMetadataBuffer().getCount());                      
    }
}).start();
```

Including the query statement the code looks like:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       //mGoogleApiClient is connected and mRootDrive is a folder in the drive account
       DriveFolder f = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGoogleApiClient, mRootDriveId);
       MetadataResult fDataresult = f.getMetadata(mGoogleApiClient).await();

       // Will print the right name of the folder
       Log.i(Tag, "Folder name " + fDataresult.getMetadata().getTitle());

       Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "tmp.txt")).build();

       MetadataBufferResult result = f.queryChildren(mGoogleApiClient, query).await();
       MetadataBuffer d = result.getMetadataBuffer();

       // Will be 0 even if the file exist in the folder
       Log.i(Tag, "Number of children " + d.getCount());
    }
 }).start();
```

After further investigation it seems that there are some issues with synchronizing the data between the app and google drive. If I use google drives UI in my app and choose a file then this file will be listed but no other file. I have tried to use Drive.DriveApi.requestSync, with the same result.

If I understand this right, then GoogleApiClient scope can only be files and folders that the app has been created or been viewed not all folders and files. What I was searching for was the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive. This scope is not handled by GoogleApiClient.

Comment: *Why* do you need that? Are you creating a cross-cloud file manager?

Comment: First this is a project for me to learn how to interact with goole drive. The project will go and featch pictures and show them in a ImageView control, nothing fancy. The problem is that the pictures has been uploaded with help of Crome browser and not the android app. It would not have been any problem if the app uploaded the pictures instead of doing it with the Crome browser. What I'm trying to do now is to use the google-api-java-client instead of the Google api.